# Catch resizing of window in Silverlight Popup

Tags: silverlight-4.0, resize, popup

I'm using a usercontrol with a popup element in it to create some kind of notification system.
There's the possibility that some notifications will be non-timed, so they stay open until the user interacts with it. This works allright, but when the user resizes the browser, the popup control has the wrong size.

I've tried catching the sizechanged on the usercontrol, but that doesn't get called (seems obvious now).

The one solution I have is catching the sizechanged on the mainwindow and applying it to the usercontrol. This notification usercontrol is singleton, so I can do it once and all notifications will have the right size. I just don't feel like this is the right solution.

Any other ideas on this matter?